# Make [vm] a synonym of [virtual-machine]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The [vm](/questions/tagged/vm) tag wiki defines VM as representing [virtual-machine](/questions/tagged/virtual-machine).

Some questions are tagged with both and some are tagged with one or the other.

Comment: You can retag 537 questions in a little under an hour.  Why not just do that?

Comment: @casperOne because bumping 537 questions is probably not optimal.

Comment: @casperOne And a mod can easily create an alias...just sayin' :P

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII SO has different bumping rules for the front page.  These won't get bumped like that.